# timestamp query doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, variables, date

i have a timestamp problem. i would like to check a timestamp if that is in the past or future. if it is in the past, a query should happens.

up to this point i got a mysql-timestamp that will be fetched by

```
$row = $query->fetch_object();
$timestamp = $row->time
```

that contains:

```
2012-04-04 12:06:38
```

for further settings i use two more variables which will be:

```
$added = $timestamp + 1209600;  //what adds 14days (1209600 seconds) to my db-timestamp
$check = $added < time();  //what checks if the 14days have passed or not
```

okay now if i test all of these with var_dump it will return for each:

```
string(19) "2012-04-04 12:06:38" at var_dump($timestamp)
int(1211612) at var_dump($added)
bool(true) at var_dump($check)
```

so my problem is, that the following query will be executed all the time, even in case of when the 14days should have been passed. i know that because i changed the timestamp to earlier date in january. here is my query:

```
if ($check === true){
    $update = $db->query("UPDATE table SET xy='1' WHERE x='$x'");
    }
```

something seems to be wrong and i have no clue what that might be.

Comment: Let's see the query before `$query->fetch_object()`. Are you using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function to convert a TIMESTAMP column into an integer in the query? If not, then $timestamp is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with barsju. The result from MySQL is a string of the DateTime entry and not actually a timestamp. Another option that would keep it within PHP is `strtotime($string);` that will translate the string into its timestamp. All that matters is that you get a timestamp before your check.

I would do it on this line of your example:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row->time);
```

I believe there are also a couple other ways to get MySQL to return the timestamp instead as well.

Comment: exactly, it was a converting problem. thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your trying to add a string and and int.

Maybe you should try converting the timestamp to and int before adding your constant to it.

You can do it directly in the query when you are selecting the timestamp using for instance the `TO_SECONDS()` method:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: And this might also give you some good ideas: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php